# Missing disk file from clonezilla image

Tags: restore, disk-image, clonezilla

Tried to restore an old Clonezilla image (2013) to the HDD I had originally restored with the image, I now find I do not get the "**restoredisk**" option when trying to restore using Clonezilla Live. I found an answer on here regarding missing disk and parts files would prevent the restore ([Clonezilla restore from Samba - no 'restoredisk' option](https://superuser.com/questions/623867/clonezilla-restore-from-samba-no-restoredisk-option?rq=1)). I reviewed my image and noticed it is missing the **disk** file.

Is there a way to create the disk or parts files to fix this issue should it arise again?

Or, is there an alternative way of restoring the disk/partition with the image I currently have without the disk (or parts files)?

EDIT: Might have found an answer to the last question - https://serverfault.com/questions/35639/extracting-files-from-clonezilla-images. Will try this today.